# How to undestand functors in the Nix expression language?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, nix

I'm having a bit of trouble parsing this. But as I write it out, I think I may have it.

```
let add = { __functor = self: x: x + self.x; };
    inc = add // { x = 1; };
in inc 1
```

First, is `self` a keyword like in many OO languages or is this just a regular name?

Secondly, I'm trying to understand what the multiple `:` are doing in the definition of `__functor`, but this is probably a failing of my basic familiarity with Nix expressions, but I guess what is happening is that both `self` and `x` are arguments to `__functor`, i.e., it looks like it is probably a curried function.

So really, `__functor` here is what `fmap` would be in Haskell, I think, and `self` (`add`) is the functor itself, and `x: x + self.x` is what the function mapped by `fmap` would be in Haskell.

Comment: Yes, it's a curried function. `__functor` is just the function to actually call if the set is "called" (with the set itself implicitly passed as the first argument), so `inc 1` is the same as `inc.__functor inc 1`.

Comment: Ah, right, I botched that a bit. I guess I haven't thought of Sets as being functors much so far, but rather as objects, in a category. Maybe there are some better examples, but I guess in the loose analogy of Functors being a form of container, a Set can feel like a container.

Comment: Some interesting discussion on Sets as Functors in Haskell: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2090x3/ask_rhaskell_why_is_there_no_functor_instance_for/

Comment: Nix sets are not Haskell sets. `__functor` here is being used in the C++ sense (a callable object), rather than a mapping between two categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` is not a keyword, just an ordinary parameter name.  You are correct that the right-hand side of `__functor` is a curried function of two arguments.  The Nix interpreter ensures that `__functor` is passed the appropriate value for `self`, at the call site `inc 1`; `__functor` is handled specially, even though it's not a keyword per se.

Your example is nearly the same as:

`let add = a: b: a + b
    inc = add 1
in inc 1`

In a larger program it might be useful to be able to override `add.x` elsewhere.

As noted in the comments, Nix uses "functor" in the sense of an object (here, set) that can be used syntactically like a function.

Passing `self` this way is Nix's version of "Objects are closures".  The technique is used many places in Nixpkgs, with & without the `__functor` feature, to get the usual benefits of Objects, including extension (~ structural subtyping) & late binding.